# python express a set as a sum/difference of other sets

Tags: python, sum, set, combinations

I am using python to implement a solution to geometry problems like this:
[[a geometry problem where one is required to express the shaded area as a sum /difference of the shapes in the figure]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKWZq.png)

In this problem, one is needed to express the shaded region as sum/difference of shapes and calculate the area accordingly.

For example,

Shaded area = subregion A + C + E

Big Semicircle = A + B + C

Small Semicircle = C + D + E

Triangle = B + C + D

Hence, area of shaded = A + B + C + (C + D + E) - (B + C + D)

Hence, to solve such problems, I need an algorithm which can express a query set consisting of subregions (A,C,E.... ) as the sum  or difference (no union or intersections required) of a number of `shape` sets in the dictionary (e.g B, C, D)

I intend to do it by brute force way (trying all combinations of all the shapes detected) , however , when the figure gets complicated , like here, 
[Figure with many small shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvXx7.png), the complexity can get out of control.

Is there an efficient way of solving this problem?

Many Thanks

Comment: (Not related to question) There's a 90º angle between triangle's 4 and 8 sides? also how do you store the shapes (the ones that are delimited by curves)?

Comment: yes. It a right triangle.  I first find the subregions using an region segmentation algorithm (i.e find the white spaces/shaded spaces that are bounded by black lines). Then I find the shapes using some shape detection algorithm (like hough circles) . I find the footprint of each shape (i.e pixels occupied by the shape) and compare them to the footprint of subregions . If all the pixels in a subregion are included in a shape, then its included. From then on, I simply store the subregion definition of shapes as sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to solve this equation:

```
A + C + E = x(A + B + C) + y(C + D + E) + z(B + C + D)
```

Like this:

A + C + E = A * ( x ) + B * ( x + z) + C * ( y + z ) + D * ( z + y ) + E * ( y )

A * ( x - 1 ) + B * ( x + z ) + C * ( x + y + z - 1 ) + D * ( z + y ) + E * ( y - 1 ) = 0

As A,B,C,D and E are always not zero, Therefore we have:

```
x - 1 = 0
x + z = 0
x + y + z - 1 = 0
z + y = 0
y - 1 = 0
```

Which gives y = 1, z = -1 and x = 1, or

A + C + E = (A + B + C) + (C + D + E) - (B + C + D).

So now we just have to do that same stuff in Python.

```
import numpy as np

shadow = [1,0,1,0,1]
big_circle = [1,1,1,0,0]
small_circle = [0,0,1,1,1]
triangle = [0,1,1,1,0]
universe = [big_circle, small_circle, triangle]
print("shadow : " + str(shadow) )
print("universe : " + str(universe) )
variables = [0] * len(universe)
equations = []
for key in zip(*universe):
    equations.append(list(key))
print("equations : " + str(equations) )
a = np.array(equations)
b = np.array(shadow)
x = np.linalg.lstsq(a,b)
print("Result: \n" )
print( str(x[0]) )
```

This is what you'll get:

```
shadow : [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
universe : [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
equations : [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
Result: 

[ 1.  1. -1.]
```

If you do this for other settings and you get a non-integer result, then it's not possible to produce the shaded area as a combination of the shapes you supplied the program.

Comment: Hi Ruan, Appreciate your answer. I tried your method. However, can I ask,I think the result of lstsq  gets a tuple of (solutions, residuals, rank and singular values)? Can   I get list of possible solutions by looping over it?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I fixed my answer.